# Fetch column names in Mysqli via PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

My goal is to fetch the names of the columns in a mysql table. But I can't figure it out.

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `" . $datenbankid . "`");
        $stmt -> execute();
        $iteration = 0;
        while($finfo = $stmt->fetch()){
            $response["testresult".$iteration] = $finfo;
            $iteration++;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

This returns true for every column but not the name. I also tried `fetch_fields()` but this ends in an error "unspecified function".

Comment: Try to use `->query()` instead of `->prepare()` for this.

Comment: I did this a few minutes ago. This is actually working. Now I only have to extract the field value. Maybe a little hint? ;-)

Comment: I managed to do it. $row['Field'] does the trick. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could run a `DESCRIBE mytable;` sql command and parse the columns from that.